# Query derived objects with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, collections, tfs

I have a collection of type LinkCollection. This collection holds several Links. What I need to do is get the WorkItemLinkCollection from the LinkCollection, and get the WorkItemLink types from the WorkItemLinkCollection.

I have the following query, but I cannot expose the WorkItemLink's properties. They do not come up in intellisense.

I want all the links in the link collection that do not have a ReferenceName of system.linktypes.dependency. I'd imagine the query id want would be something like this. Remember, I have the property typed out below, in the actual code it doesn't show "LinkTypeEnd"

```
LinkCollection collection = GetLinks(workItemStore, workItemId);

            var query = from link in collection.Cast<WorkItemLinkCollection>()
                        let workItemLink = link.Cast<WorkItemLink>()
                        where workItemLink.LinkTypeEnd.LinkType.ReferenceName.ToLower() != "system.linktypes.dependency"
                        select link;
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: What' the " type LinkCollection" ? Could you show some examples?

Comment: Can you share the code for GetLinks() method?